# Magento 2 Add to cart out of stock item issue

Tags: magento2, addtocart, out-of-stock

I have a product with 0 quantity and Out of Stock Product, and it is showing on front-end. Customer is able to do add that product to cart.

I run all commands like:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

but issue not solved.

Please tell me the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of research, I found the solution.

System configuration was wrong for Backorders.

[image]

Now I make it like this:
[image]

and it makes my day :)

Answer (score 0):

The command that you have used for `reindex` is wrong. Please use

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Also check the value of

> Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Stock Options->"Display Out
>   of Stock Products" is '**NO**'

and the value of

> Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->"Product Stock
>   Options"->"Out-of-Stock Threshold" is **zero**

if you are using Magento 2.3

Comment: Please check my quesion again.

Comment: and I wanted to display  out of stock products, if I make it no or 0 it will not display out of stock product in frontend. My issue is add to cart button is showing. customer is able to add to cart out of stock item.